# Python request post data with auth

Tags: python, authentication, post, flask, python-requests

I have little problem with requests post and auth
In frontdend application is this code:

```
url = "http://localhost:9886/"
username = "Admin"
password = "SuperSecretPassword"
payload = {'sex' : 'male'}
request = requests.post(url, data = payload, auth = (username, password))
```

And in backend this:

```
data = request.get_json()
return jsonify({"data" : data})
```

But backend app don't receive any data, so can someone help?...Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear on what data you're looking for, so I've provided two potential solutions:

#### Backend:

The auth will be present in the header of the request object in your backend.

```py
b64user_pass = request.headers.get("Authorization")
```

#### Frontend:

If your endpoint is expecting `json` be sure to make the request with the `Content-Type` header

```py
request = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", auth=(user, pass))

# Or even better:
request = requests.post(url, json=payload, auth=(user, pass))
```